Laplace Equation on Bounded Domain with $0$ Boundary Condition
Say I have some connected domain $\Omega$ which is a subset of finite volume of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and on the domain I have Laplace's equation for some function $u$, $\Delta=0$. Say the boundary conditions are defined by $f(x)=0$ on the entire boundary. Is it necessarily true that $u$ much be equal to $0$ on the entire domain? Are there more restrictions to impose? Or is $u$ not necessarily $0$ but just constant?

The answer is definelty positive that $u=0$ if you replace "finite volume domain" by "bounded domain".  Or are you asking about the non-standard case of finite volume?
